# File locking in Windows with Jetty 9 and Maven plugin

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

There is a lot of information available on the this subject, but I can't get it to work in Jetty 9. The most recent approach I found was: [Jetty Maven Plugin is ignoring custom webdefault.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988019/jetty-maven-plugin-is-ignoring-custom-webdefault-xml)

I extracted the webdefault.xml from my maven repository. Then I set `useFileMappedBuffer` to `false` and placed it within my project as `jetty-maven-plugin-webdefault.xml`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.0.M4</version>
    <configuration>
        <webAppConfig>
            <defaultsDescriptor>src/main/resources/jetty-maven-plugin-webdefault.xml<</defaultsDescriptor>
        </webAppConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I execute `jetty:run`, I see my webdefault.xml is referenced:

```
[INFO] Web defaults = src/main/resources/jetty-maven-plugin-webdefault.xml
```

But I still have file locking issues in Windows (using IntelliJ IDEA 11). Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Check this answer [How to prevent jetty from locking static resources](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35863046/1690578)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging a little deeper, I found a bug in Jetty 9.0.0.M4 causing it to ignore the useFileMappedBuffer parameter: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=395885

I've proposed a patch and hope it will be fixed before the release :)

Comment: thanks, we'll try and have this in M6 or RC1, whichever the next release turns out to be (we have M5 staged atm)

Comment: `version 9.3.0.M2` does't work for me. All Class file are lock.

Comment: @zhaoyou I have the same problem; locked class files. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @DanielRijkhof Yes. I using pulgin   `org.mortbay.jetty` `jetty-maven-plugin` `8.1.3.v20120416` and add connector ` <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">` in Configuration element.

Answer (score 4):

I downgraded to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
</dependency>
```

Which still respects the web default.