# Jetty locking static files in Windows

Tags: jetty

I do not see, my changes of the static files.

In the another resources recommending the following method:

Include to the webdefault.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value> <!-- change to false -->
</init-param>
```

But it not the working. Have any idea?

Jetty version: 8.1.8.v20121106

Comment: Which version of Jetty?

Comment: Check this answer [How to prevent jetty from locking static resources](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35863046/1690578)

Answer (score 1):

The `useFileMappedBuffer` init-param is for file locking by the DefaultServlet.

If you can change your static files with an editor and save, with no error, then this configurable has no bearing for your question "I do not see my changes of the static files".

The likely scenarios:

- Browser is caching the original response
- The file you changed on disk is not the file that is being served by Jetty.

Comment: Ok. I changed all files on the hard drive which have name like to my static html. For check browser cache I run another browser and not see any changes. In the webdefaults.xml useFileMappedBuffer is false.