# Grails 2.4.0.RC1 seems to lock javascript files on Windows 7 - 64bit

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.4.0.RC1 (and JDK 1.7.0_55) and whenever I browse to any app view that makes use of javascript files from the web-app folder, the java process seems to lock those files.
So I cannot work on any of those javascript files any more since when I try to save changes Windows 7 will not let me do it.

I used Process Explorer to check which process is locking the files and it's the java process running the grails app indeed.

At first I thought that this problem could be related to the new asset-pipeline:1.8.7 plugin which I am using. So I uninstalled it to check if the problem was still there... and it was.

The same app was running on Grails 2.3.5 just fine (although we were using an older JDK too... I must check with JDK 1.7.0_55).

By the way, something similar happened with a much older version of Grails: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3585

Is Anyone experiencing the same problem?

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tested this problem running the app on different versions of java and these are my results:

```
Win7-64bits, grails2.4.0.RC1, jdk1.7.0_55 -> PROBLEM OCCURS
Win7-64bits, grails2.4.0.RC1, jdk1.7.0_25 -> PROBLEM OCCURS
Win7-64bits, grails2.4.0.RC1, jdk1.6.0_18 -> OK
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I created a blank app (which uses Tomcat by default) and everything works fine.
The same blank app using jetty-plugin (with Jetty8) DOES present the problem.
I am further investigating this now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
It had to do with the jetty-plugin indeed.

On the official version of the plugin 2.0.3 which uses Jetty7, the locking problem is NOT present. But this plugin uses a very old version of Jetty, so it's no use.

On the branch of the plugin created to run Jetty8:
https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-jetty/tree/2.0.x
... the problem is there.

Also, on the new grails jetty plugin version 3.0.x (which uses Jetty 9.0.x), the problem is there too!

**UPDATE 1:**

Have a look at:
[Jetty locking static files in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837716/jetty-locking-static-files-in-windows)
Apparently the "useFileMappedBuffer" init-param of Jetty has to be set to false to prevent file locking.
You can use a local version of the jetty plugin and modify the above-mentioned property on [jetty-plugin]/grails-app/conf/webdefault.xml