# How does jetty auto reload static resources(html,css,jss)

Tags: java, spring, jetty

I just use jetty to serve my web project without any XML, but it still didnot auto-reload  event I set `contextHandler.getInitParams().put("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.useFileMappedBuffer", "false");`

```
private void startJetty(int port) throws Exception {
    logger.debug("Starting server at port {}", port);
    Server server = new Server(port);
    server.setHandler(getServletContextHandler(getContext()));
    server.start();
    logger.info("Server started at port {}", port);
    server.join();
}

private static ServletContextHandler getServletContextHandler(WebApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
    WebAppContext contextHandler = new WebAppContext();
    contextHandler.getInitParams().put("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.useFileMappedBuffer", "false");
    contextHandler.getInitParams().put("cacheContro", "max-age=0, public");

    contextHandler.setErrorHandler(null);
    contextHandler.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
    contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DispatcherServlet(context)), MAPPING_URL);
    contextHandler.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    contextHandler.setResourceBase(new ClassPathResource("static").getURI().toString());
    return contextHandler;
}

private static WebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);
    context.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles(DEFAULT_PROFILE);
    return context;
}
```

PS: My jetty is version 9.2, I use springmvc to be the contextHandler, I have tried lots of ways and answers in websites,such `https://gist.github.com/raymyers/5323304` , `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184312/how-to-make-jetty-dynamically-load-static-pages` , but still not work, I will be waiting for solutions.