# Cannot reload static file on Jetty server from IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

I'm working on a project in IntelliJ 2016.2.4 (Windows 7), where it's set up to deploy to a local Jetty 9.3 server using a standard "Jetty server" run configuration.

Reloading ordinary Java classes (in debug mode) works normally. But when I try to redeploy the static file `main.js`, IntelliJ displays the following error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Projects\portal\build\exploded\portal-project\js\main.js (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)`

Following [this](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/troubleshooting-locked-files-on-windows.html), I tried to make the modification

```xml
<init-param>
  <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value> <!--Changed from <param-value>false</param-value>-->
</init-param>
```

to `etc/webdefault.xml` of the Jetty distribution directory. No other changes have been made to the distribution. In particular, `jetty.deploy.defaultsDescriptorPath` has the default value `<Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/webdefault.xml` set in `etc/jetty-deploy.xml`.

Unfortunately, this didn't make any difference. Setting `maxCachedFiles` to `0` as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16775518/883073) also didn't work.

I found somewhere that the Jetty Maven plugin might solve the problem, but the project doesn't use Maven (nor Gradle).

Edit: I don't know if it has any significance, but on startup I get the log line

`2016-09-21 17:27:33.275:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not recommended. [...]`

Comment: I have been unable to replicate this, though I am on Windows 10. Oddly enough, I cannot get the error to manifest at all on Win10 using a DefaultServlet. I **can** get the error when using a ResourceHandler, but making the change in webdefault.xml clears it. Are you sure you have no other calls in say a web.xml or elsewhere in your code conflicting this?

Answer (score 4):

I am on Windows 10 Pro, running IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4 and Jetty 9.3.10.v20160621 - and I WAS able to duplicate Halle's results. Editing webdefault.xml did not help.

[How to make Jetty dynamically load "static" pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184312/how-to-make-jetty-dynamically-load-static-pages/16775518#16775518) has the answer - add a context parameter to your webapp's web.xml.

But as written, it won't work with newer versions of Jetty, as it refers to a namespace, "org.mortbay", which Jetty hasn't used in at least a few years now. Here's what works for me. Essentially the same thing as in that other post, but this snippet uses org.eclipse, not org.mortbay:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now, to address your other point...

Best current practice is to have a separate **jetty.home** directory and **jetty.base** directory. The idea is that jetty.home contains binaries, libraries and the pristine, DEFAULT configs. Everything you need to override, you override in whichever directory you have set as jetty.base.

My production J2EE servers run Jetty, and they have separate home and base directories. It's cleaner, and if you set things up that way, it's a lot less likely to break things. As http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-base-and-home.html says:

> Jetty Home should always be treated as a standard of truth. All configuration modifications, changes and additions should be made in the appropriate Jetty Base directory.

My laptop does not have separate home and base directories, I get that warning when I am developing and I don't care about it. You can run Jetty without a separate jetty.base - it won't cause any issues. It's just not a BCP. I definitely would recommend separate home and base directories in a production environment, but on a dev server, I don't think it is a big deal.